# Need transistor circuit to supply pulse/gnd signals to optical switch

Tags: transistors, switches, analog

I am a digital designer so anything analog is out of my expertise. I need to control an optical 2x2 switch with the following truth table:

[image]

The pulse is in the msec range and the driver current is about 200mA.

Link to data sheet shown below:

https://agiltron.com/PDFs/CL%202x2%202-Stage%20Series%20Switch.pdf

I have an FPGA that can control the transistors but not sure how to arrange them?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: show link to datasheet

Comment: Also, a) what is the I/O power supply voltage for the FPGA;  b) what is the actual output voltage range on an FPGA output pin?  Off the top, this smells like two small-signal transistors, like a 2N4401 and 2N4403, and two resistors, per switch input pin.

Comment: Matty, why not just use two half-bridges and place the switch between them? You could use four outputs and drive all four transistors, directly. Or you should arrange things so that there is a circuit surrounding the two half-bridges so that only one control line is required. If you have the pins to waste, I'd just go with driving all four, individually. More control over the behavior that way.

Answer (score 0):

Given the specs on the switch I'd go for some small integrated H-bridge circuit, like the one used for small stepper motors. They have (by pure chance!) two full bridges and are trivially driven by logic. As a bonus you have usually many nice protections.

In fact probably these switch have coils inside that moves the actual switch assembly around the optical path, so I think the kind of electrical load is the same. Many, many, manufacturers do these things, they are used, for example, in throttle valve control for engines.

Comment: Wouldn't the H bridge circuit leave the switch (load) at 2.5V on both sides if control is inactive? If this is the case, the datasheet seems to assume that the sides would be at GND unless a pulse is applied. Not sure if this would work then. Thoughts?

Comment: An H-bridge circulates current… in idle state the branches are disconnected, not at 2.5V (maybe some leakage from the diodes). If you want to be sure you can drive it in braking mode with both ends to 0V

Comment: so I looked at a H bridge circuit (simplified). It looks like if I keep the top two transistors off and the bottom two on, it will gnd out the two terminals to the load? Sorry I don't know how to add a image in a comment.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. It's used in motors for braking, so you may see it named that way in bridge documentation.